# How to delete a row if the row is present in next page or some other page JQuery datatables

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables, datatables-1.10

I have row data present in some page say page no 3 but i am in page no 1, i want to delete row present in page 3.I have tried below code but it did not work.please assist.

```
$('#tableid').DataTable().rows($('#idofthatrow')).remove().draw(false);
```

Comment: You'd have to set a value somewhere indicating what rows are present on page X. Maybe localStorage is an option here. What does raise a question for me, is why the rows are present on both pages. Maybe rethink your 'adding-rows' logic.

Comment: Hi m@Matthijs , I have requirement to add latest data in page 1 and if the row is present in any other page, then remove the old row.

Comment: How do you know which row you want to remove? Datatables doesn't add unique ids onto rows by default. Where are you getting `#idofthatrow`?

Comment: While creating row , i am adding id externally

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery `$()` method will not work because rows for pages other than current do not exist in DOM.

API method [`row()`](http://datatables.net/reference/api/row%28%29) and [`rows()`](http://datatables.net/reference/api/rows%28%29) accept row ID as an argument, see [`row-selector`](http://datatables.net/reference/type/row-selector#string---#ID) documentation.

Your code could be rewritten as:

```
$('#tableid').DataTable().row('#idofthatrow').remove().draw(false);
```

Comment: Could you also tell how to retrieve the data of the row, if it is not present in the DOM?

Comment: @user3932103 the same way as gyrocode explain -> `$('#tableid').DataTable().row('#idofthatrow').data()`